# sort ManyToMany association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities

1. Quiz
2. Question

the Question entity has a field named `order`, I want to sort the questions of a Quiz but it doesn't work.

```
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Quiz\CoreBundle\Entity\Question", mappedBy="quizes", cascade={"persist", "remove", "merge"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"order"= "ASC"})
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */
    protected $questions;
```

The field in **question** entity:

```
  /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="question_order",type="integer")
     * @Groups({"public", "admin"})
     */

    protected $order;
```

please help

Comment: I typically order my records when I query them, not in the entity definition.  Have you tried that?